# Return a class instance as a pointer in D

Tags: d

I am trying to compile the following code in D

```
void* instantiate(_LV2_Descriptor* descriptor, 
  double sample_rate, char * bundle_path, 
  LV2_Feature** features) {
  Plugin plugin = new Bleep(sample_rate, features);
  return &plugin;
}
```

but I get the following error

```
../src/lv2/plugin.d(38): Error: escaping reference to local plugin
```

What is the right way to create a class instance and a return it as a pointer? Also in such a way that it is not claimed by GC. There is another callback for object deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Plugin` and `Bleep` are clearly classes given that you're assigning a new `Bleep` to a `Plugin` variable, and there's no `*` on `plugin`'s declaration. So, `plugin` is a reference, not a pointer. `&plugin` is returning a pointer to a reference - in this case, one which is a local variable (hence the error). It's not what you want at all. You can explicitly cast `plugin` to `void*` if you really want a pointer, but that *is* a somewhat abnormal thing to do. I *assume* that you're interfacing with C code, otherwise there really shouldn't be a reason to cast to `void*`. Class objects are references, not pointers, and should be left as such if possible. If you're passing it to C code (presumably which will then call your D code later, since C doesn't know what to do with a D class), then you're more or less stuck using `void*`, but I'd advise avoiding it otherwise.

The GC won't free the object as long as your D code has a reference to it, but if you pass it to a C function and don't leave any reference to it in your D code, it *will* be collected at some point by the GC.

If you're going to be explicitly freeing the object yourself, then don't use the GC. `delete` is scheduled for deprecation, and you're not normally supposed to be freeing stuff on the GC heap yourself. That's the GC's job. You can call `destroy` on an object to destroy it (e.g. `destroy(obj);`), but the memory won't be freed (rather the destructor will be called, and the object's vtable will be zeroed out so that using it will result in a segfault).

If you really want to be allocating and deallocating an object yourself, then you should be using `malloc` and `free`, though that's definitely more complicated. You'd have to allocate a chunk of memory the size of the object with `malloc`, and then use [`std.conv.emplace`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#emplace) to construct the class in that chunk of memory in order to create the object. Then to free it, you'd have to explicitly call its destructor, and then call `free` on that memory. Work is being done on custom allocators which should definitely make this easier (probably making it much closer to `alloc.new!MyClass(args)` and `alloc.free(obj)`), but they haven't been completed yet and so aren't yet in the standard library.

One way to handle allocating and freeing the object using the GC if you don't need deterministic destruction would be to simply keep a reference to the object in your D code and then set that reference to `null` when you want to free the object. It won't free it until the GC decides to collect it, but it makes it so that the GC won't collect before you're done with it and so that it will be able to collect it once you are.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I will try normal instantiation and GC.addRoot(cast(void*)plugin) at first.

Answer (score 1):

just return the `plugin` it is already a pointer

also as long as you keep a reference to it, it won't be claimed by GC

Comment: `plugin` is _not_ a pointer. It's a reference. As a new `Bleep` is being assigned to a `Plugin`, `Plugin` and `Bleep` are clearly classes, so a `Plugin` variable is a reference. If `Plugin` were a struct, and he was instantiating a new `Plugin`, then the result would be a `Plugin*`, and then _that_ would be a pointer, but since it's a class, it's a reference.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis in D a class reference IS a pointer and implicitly convertible to `void*`

Comment: No, it's not. A reference is similar to a pointer, but it's not the same, and the type system does _not_ treat them the same (e.g. references are polymorphic, pointers are not - even when you have a pointer to a class).

Comment: @JonathanMDavis yet in D (the language we are talking about) object references are implemented as a simple pointer to where the object resides in memory

Comment: It doesn't really matter how it's implemented underneath the hood. The language treats them as distinct and incompatible types. You can't assign a reference to a pointer or vice versa. If you declare `Plugin*` and `Plugin` is a class, you're declaring a pointer to a reference to a `Plugin`, not a pointer to a `Plugin`. The fact that it's essentially a pointer underneath means that explicitly casting to and from `void*` should work, but implicitly casting to and from `void*` won't, and the type system does not treat pointers and references as the same at all.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan that pointers and references are really distinct things.